# #R read.csv file and miss attributes

Tags: r, excel, csv

I read a basic first round csv file from excel (iris.csv) to R. I used read.csv and i lost my columns. Any idea where i went wrong ?

Thanks for help!
Have good day

[This is the csv file:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spFdl.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would open the file in a text editor, not Excel. See if perhaps it is actually delimited by tabs or fixed white space. That is a very common reason for getting one monster column with a weird jammed up header. If that is the case you can use `read.table( sep ='insert sep type here')` to set the proper read format and be on your way!

Answer (score 0):

`read.csv` has a `header` argument, set it to `TRUE`

`read.csv(file = "iris.csv", header = TRUE)`